# Trying to write via logstash to elasticsearch but getting - Failed to install template

Tags: elasticsearch, authentication, logstash, logstash-configuration

**EDIT**
I've added a picture of the logs (from the logstash startup)

Trying to write log files to elasticsearch via logstash.

Unfortunately unable to write to ES since logstash (which is deployed on docker) raises the error-
`Failed to install template. {Message => "Template file ''could not be found!"....`

index already exists in elasticsearch.

Environment variables for logstash in output filter are as such:

````
user=> "some user"
password=> "some password"
index=> "some index"
template_name=> "some template name"}```![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tQbA.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8E5y.jpg)
````

Comment: What happens if you remove the `template_name` parameter? You probably don't need any index template since your index already exists.

Comment: tried not using the ```template name``` it made no difference..

Comment: Can you share the logs from when Logstash is starting up ?

Comment: What is the `template` option in your output? If you are using a custom `template_name` then you need to pass the path to the `json` file with the template using the `template` option. Your error is pretty clear, the template file could not be found.